# How to perform multiple clicks on a view in Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

In my application I had a bug, where the app crashed when I clicked a button multiple times. I fixed the bug and now I want to write an Espresso UI Test to verify that the bug is fixed. So my question is, is it possible to perform multiple clicks on one view like a button and how can I do this?

This is what I already have but I'm not sure if this the correct way to implement this

`onView(withContentDescription("Foo")).perform(click(), doubleClick())`

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/ViewInteraction#perform), the `perform` method of the `ViewInteraction` class, takes a vararg of `ViewAction` objects.
So your code:

```
onView(withContentDescription("Foo")).perform(click(), doubleClick())
```

seems correct.